# Keyframes are not automatically saved in pose mode with auto-keying on (2.79b)

Tags: animation, armature, keyframes

I'm running into an issue on Blender 2.79b where the correct keyframes are not automatically inserted into the timeline when auto-keying is on. When transforming a bone, a keyframe is inserted with the value as it was set prior to the transformation. I also noticed some strange behavior:

- If I toggle "Confirm on Release" or "Edit Grease Pencil" the keyframe is updated with the correct value.
- Deleting all keyframes and starting with a clean timeline fixes the issue.

Is this a bug or maybe one of my keyframes is in a weird state? I checked the dope sheet and nothing appears to be locked.

Here's a video of the behavior: https://streamable.com/na4ze and the .blend file: http://www.filedropper.com/armadillo

Thanks

Comment: ok so I told you: "Go to the Outliner panel, you can see that there is an animation inside the mesh, I guess it is not supposed to be there, right click over it and Clear Animation Data, now it should work." But it didn't solve the problem... I'm going to dig further... strange because sometimes I can make it work...

Comment: I don't find where does the problem come from  :p   I hope someone will